# project.json and Microsoft.Bcl.Build

Tags: .net, nuget, project.json

I would like to use project.json in a net4.0 library instead of package.config
It s working perfectly well but for use of Microsoft.Bcl.Build which enable the use of async/await. Any idea how I can correct this.

Thanks

Comment: What does not work when you tried? Also, it is `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` not `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` (which is a dependency of `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`) which you should be doing for async/await in .NET 4.0

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: "System.Security.VerificationException: Method System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted: type argument 'Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TAwaiter'." Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Just create a Net 4.0 ClassLibrary project. Add project.json {
  "frameworks": {
    "net40": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "Windows": {
          "type": "build"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29"
  }
} Then Create a class like this public class Class1
    {

        public async Task Test()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });
        }
    } and try to compile

Comment: @Bhugot What exactly happens when you do that? What error are you getting?

Comment: Task does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Comment: someone got some hints on this?